# Pivot in sql query using union

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

What is wrong with this query:

```
 select * from ( select [date],CountType,[Count]  from(

select COUNT(Id) as [Count],'TotalCustomer' as CountType, cast(DATEADD(day,3,[JobCardDate])as date) as [date] FROM [Honda_db].[dbo].[Post Service Feedback] 
where cast(DATEADD(day,3,[JobCardDate]) as date) between '2015-11-26' and  '2015-12-26' group by cast(DATEADD(day,3,[JobCardDate]) as date)
 union  
select COUNT(Id) as [Count],'NotCalled' as CountType, cast(DATEADD(day,3,[JobCardDate]) as date) as [Date] from [Honda_db].[dbo].[Post Service Feedback] 
  where  cast(DATEADD(day,3,[JobCardDate]) as date) between '2015-11-26' and  '2015-12-26' and 
  ([IsCalled] is null or [IsCalled] ='No')  group by cast(DATEADD(day,3,[JobCardDate]) as date)
  ) as s
  PIVOT
(
    SUM([Count])
    FOR CountType IN (TotalCustomer,NotCalled)
) AS pvt
```

According to the syntax of pivot I think I am on right track. Refereed from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query).

Here is the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'pvt'.

Comment: did it not work? did you get an error? if so, what is the error message? add all these details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

1. `FOR CountType IN (TotalCustomer,NotCalled)` this should be delimited
2. Extra `select * from (` in the beginning

Here is the query after correction:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    COUNT(Id) AS [Count] ,
                    'TotalCustomer' AS CountType ,
                    CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 3, [JobCardDate]) AS DATE) AS [date]
          FROM      [Honda_db].[dbo].[Post Service Feedback]
          WHERE     CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 3, [JobCardDate]) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-11-26' AND '2015-12-26'
          GROUP BY  CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 3, [JobCardDate]) AS DATE)
          UNION
          SELECT    COUNT(Id) AS [Count] ,
                    'NotCalled' AS CountType ,
                    CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 3, [JobCardDate]) AS DATE) AS [Date]
          FROM      [Honda_db].[dbo].[Post Service Feedback]
          WHERE     CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 3, [JobCardDate]) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-11-26' AND '2015-12-26'
                    AND ( [IsCalled] IS NULL
                          OR [IsCalled] = 'No'
                        )
          GROUP BY  CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 3, [JobCardDate]) AS DATE)
        ) AS s PIVOT
( SUM([Count]) FOR CountType IN ( [TotalCustomer], [NotCalled] ) ) AS pvt
```

Comment: result says invalid column name 'CountType' and 'Count', why so ?

Comment: @HotCoolStud, I have change to `*`